# how to pass implicit val to base call in scala

Tags: scala, automation, implicit

I am new to Scala and still learning. And I am trying to perform/design following approach:

```
class BasePage (implicit val webDriver: WebDriver, val environment: String) {...}

class LoginPage extends BasePage {...}

class testSpecs extends Specification{
    new WithBrowser(webDriver = currentDriver, app = application){

    implicit val webDriver= browser.webDriver
    implicit val environment = s"localhost:$port"

    val loginPage = new LoginPage()
    ...
}
```

What I want is to make webDriver and environment available (when first time it is created) to all the page object classes throughout the test script/test in testSpecs.

In this approach I am getting error like :

> could not find implicit value for parameter webDriver: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

1. How can we fix this problem?
2. What are the other better approach i can use?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What about Companion Object of same Super class (LoginPage), Do we still need to pass implicit val for that?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor to `BasePage` expects 2 arguments. When class `LoginPage` is defined, those implicit values aren't in scope, so you'll have to write it like this:

```
class LoginPage(implicit val webDriver: WebDriver, val environment: String) extends BasePage {...}
```

Now `LoginPage` also has 2 implicit parameters which are passed implicitly to `BasePage`'s constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper its working with this approach, + I need to add "abstract" in BaseClass